# How to use Devise helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am trying to build a Rails server for my client while implementing Devise controllers, and am facing a lot of issues.

1. When using `Warden.authenticate(resource_name)!` for logging purpose, I get "401 unauthorized", but I am able to sign-up properly though Device's `sign_in` method.
2. While trying to use the helper method after signing in through the `auth_token` I get nil and default values for all the helper methods.

Versions:

- Rails v5.0.2
- ruby v2.2.3
- Devise v4.2.0

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format ==  'application/json' }



 before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
 before_action :authenticate_user!
 before_filter :set_current_user



  def set_current_user

      Thread.current[:current_user] = current_user

  end 


   private


  #for authenticating the token 
  def authenticate_user_from_token!

    user_id = params[:id].presence
    user       = user_id && User.find_by_id(user_id)
    puts user 
    if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token,  params[:auth_token])
      puts "about to sign in"
      sign_in user, store: false
      puts ""
    end
  end
```

user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                 :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

 skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!


    def index

    end 

    def create 

        respond_to do |format|

                  format.json {
                    if params[:user] && params[:user][:email] && params[:user][:name]# input name and email
                      @user = User.where(:email => params[:user][:email].downcase).first unless User.where(:email => params[:user][:email].downcase).count == 0 
                      if @user.nil?
                        @user = User.new
                        lookup_hash                 = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.hexdigest  
                        # @user.phone_number          = params[:user][:phone_number]
                        # @user.safe_update(%w[name email ], params[:user])
                         @user.name = params[:user][:name]
                         @user.email = params[:user][:email]

                        if params[:user][:specialization]
                            @user.specialization = params[:user][:specialization]
                        end 
                        if params[:user][:password]
                          @user.password              = params[:user][:password]
                          @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password]
                        else
                          @user.password              = lookup_hash[0,6]
                          @user.password_confirmation = lookup_hash[0,6]
                        end
                         #we have to  see wether we have to send password through mail or not.



                        #assigning auth_token at the time of registration
                        @user.assign_authentication_token
                        success = @user && @user.save
                        if success && @user.errors.empty?

                          # Jobs::Mailer.async.signup_welcome_email(@user.id).commit!
                          #Jobs::Mailer.async.new_invitation_alpha(@user.id,@user.email,@user.password).commit!



                          sign_in(:user, @user)


                          #if @user.country_code == "IN" && @user.user_persona == "doctor"
                            #show_promo_code = true
                          #end



                          render :status => :ok,
                                 :json => { :success => true,
                                            :info => "Successfully Registered! Please check you email for password",
                                            :data => { :auth_token => @user.authentication_token,
                                                      :id => @user.id.to_s
                                                        } }

                        else
                         render :status => :unprocessable_entity,
                                :json => { :success => false,
                                            :info => @user.errors,
                                            :data => {} }
                        end
                      else
                        render  :status => 409,
                                :json => { :success => false,
                                            :info => "You are already Registered!",
                                            :data => {} }
                      end

                        else
                          render :status => 412, 
                                  :json => { :success => false,
                                              :info => "User  details are  missing",
                                              :data => {} }
                        end
                  }
        end

    end              


end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   namespace :api do
     namespace :v1 do
      devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 
                'api/v1/users/sessions' }  
 end 
end 

     post '/register' => 'users#create', :as => :register    
     resources :users
     devise_for :users
     resources :preferences

end






end
```

session controller:

```
class Api::V1::Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user, :only => [:destroy]

 skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel , :destroy]
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
  before_filter :ensure_params_exist, :except => [:destroy]

  respond_to :json


  def create

            resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:user][:email]) 
            return invalid_login_attempt unless resource if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
            sign_in(:user, resource) 
            resource.assign_authentication_token
            resource.save!
            render :status => 200,
            :json => {
                       :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :data => { :auth_token => resource.authentication_token,
                                 :id => resource.id.to_s,
                                 :name => resource.name} }

  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy 
    super
    remove_auth_token params[:auth_token]


  end



  def failure
    render :status => :unauthorized,
           :json => { :success => false,
                      :info => "Login Failed",
                      :data => {} }
  end



  def remove_auth_token token
     if !token.blank?
       user = User.where(authentication_token: token).first
       if !user.nil?
         user.authentication_token = nil 
         user.save!
       end 
     end 
  end 

 protected 


    def ensure_params_exist
      return unless params[:user].blank?
       render :json=>{:message=>"missing user_login parameter"}, 
                      :status=>422 
    end

     def invalid_login_attempt 
         render :json=> {:message=>"Error with your login or password"}, 
                      :status=>401 
     end



end
```

Devise config:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ou use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

 .
  require 'devise/orm/mongoid'


  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]


  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  #
  config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false


  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  #
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11


  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 6..128


  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/


  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours


  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*','*/*', :html , :json]

  config.sign_out_via = :delete


end
```

Comment: See "[mcve]" and Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". Is this the absolute smallest amount of code necessary to duplicate the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend cleaning up your code too. The whitespace makes it difficult to read.

Comment: @theTinMan Actually  i am not aware what is causing this issue  thats why i am posting all the related code for devise and trying to remove white spaces and reformat my code